# How do you remove the underline of a text in Xamarin Editor Control on the Android Platform?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, editor, renderer

Based on the research that I've done, the suggestion was to create a renderer in Android and set the background to transparent but it did not work.
Here's the code.

```
    public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
      protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Editor> e)
      {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)

            return;

        Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(ClaimAllGraphics.Color.Transparent);
      }
   }
```

How do I remove the bottom line in an editor?
Secondly, how do I ensure I still have the enter / return keypad on the keyboard?
This is important as I have a multiline editor, so users should be able to press the enter / return keypad and move to the next line.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Remove the underline of a text in Xamarin Editor Control on the Android Platform?

Change `ClaimAllGraphics.Color.Transparent` to `null`:

```
public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)

            return;

        Control.Background = null;
        //Or Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

    }
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8XRP.gif).

Comment: Thank you, @york, this worked like a champ:
`Color bgcolor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["editableColor"];
this.Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(bgcolor.ToAndroid());`